# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channel')

Tags: angular, laravel, websocket

I configured `chat` uses `laravel` and `angular` by `pusher` everything works fine, but it gives me error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channel')`

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.websocketChannelListening();
  }

 websocketChannelListening() {
    this.echo.channel('chat')
      .listen('ChatEvent', (res:any) => {
        const message: Messages = {
          message: res.message,
          me: false,
          from: res.from
        };
        this.allMessages.push(message);
      });
  }
```

Comment: I think `this.echo` is undefined. where is the `echo` you are calling ?

Comment: `this.echo` is undefined. You need initialize or assign value to `echo` somewhere (most probably in `ngOnInit` or `constructor`)